# How to open a link in the first open new browser tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, tabs

I know that this might not be possible.

Lets say I have a list of say 50 hyperlinks. The default behavior is to open the links in a new tab when clicked. But I want to prevent the user from opening 50 tabs if he/she clicks on all 50.

So is there any way to create a hyperlink which when clicked,

1. Opens the first link in a new tab
2. Subsequent links are opened in that same tab(instead of a new tab)

If it helps, Chrome will be the browser that we would use for this. 
Is there any HTML.JS, Chrome trick that we can use? Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe this can be achieved reliably across all browsers. Setting the same `target` attribute (and even using `window.open` with a provided window name) still opens link in a new tab each time.

Answer (score 2):

Add this snippet to your code, and check.

```html
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); 
for (i=0;i<a.length;i++) { 

        if (a[i].target="_blank") { 
            a[i].target="_self" 
        } 
                         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works because it changes the URL of one window if it is opened to the link that the user clicked.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Search Engines
</title>
<script>

opened = false ;

function openMyLink(linkToOpen) {

    if (opened === false) {

        openWindow = window.open(linkToOpen,"_blank") ;
        opened = true ;
        openWindow.addEventListener("beforeunload",function () {opened = false ;}) ;

    }

    else {

        openWindow.location.href = linkToOpen ;

    }

}

</script>
<style>
a {

cursor : pointer ;
color : blue ;
text-decoration : underline ;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
Search Engines
</h1>
<br><a onclick="openMyLink('http://www.google.com/') ;">Google</a>
<br><a onclick="openMyLink('http://www.bing.com/') ;">Bing</a>
<br><a onclick="openMyLink('http://www.yahoo.com/') ;">Yahoo</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this but did not work. First link opens and nothing happens on subsequent clicks.

Comment: It work for me, but does not focus on the tab. On the subsequent clicks, the page in the other tab changes but you still need to flick to the tab yourself. If this is not the case, then comment again & I will try to fix it.

Comment: Hi Jacob, firstly would this work in chrome? And yes we would need the page to update in the tab without the user needing to click on the new tab.